# Strange lines when importing FBX file from Fusion 360. What are they?

Tags: import, .fbx, lines

[image: FBX import with and another import without. No difference in import settings.]

(Noob here.)

I get these solid black lines in most of my Fusion assembly imports. They mark the XYZ location of each body's origin point. It's not consistent though. Sometimes I see none or just one for the entire assembly. I tried to correlate this with linked vs embedded, hidden F360 origins vs visible, etc. I'm not learning anything.

The graphic shows two Fusion FBX files imported at the same time. One file has the lines and the other doesn't.

They disappear when I uncheck Extras in the Overlay panel. What are these called? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Hello, could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am new to this forum and reply/comments seem to be extra tiny. So I just now finally saw your message, The two FBX files and blend file are here:
https://kioskgroupinc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mjames_kioskgroup_com/EYvYciNJBgFNmBvO6x3haMEBREASFhhrVl8rUeqn3jwMDg
https://kioskgroupinc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mjames_kioskgroup_com/EZJ2vAuI1H5IsrM-8Y7B5sYBEViesJP9-_0iljnCPvHCBw
https://kioskgroupinc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mjames_kioskgroup_com/EU_k2xo6BGNDpgi-ejKufo4BU_NTno2kOoEvvLk2-_vHeQ

Answer (score 0):

These look like empty objects (you can create them yourself via the menu Add > Empty > Plain Axes).

AFAIK, some 3d exchange formats tend to consider groups or collections of objects as object, with transform coordinates in the 3D world. And, are therefore interpreted as "empty objects" in most importers. Which are empty objects in Blender.

You could remove them if you want, although some objects' placements might be affected by it.
If you just want to not see them and not modify your assets, I'd suggest to product-assign them a to a hidden collection.

1. In the outliner, click the New Collection button on the top left corner, name it `EmptyHidden`, uncheck its eye icon to hide it.
2. Select your empty objects (you can select one of them, then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to open the *Select Group* menu and chose *Types* to select all objects of same type)
3. Open the *Move to Collection* menu > select the `EmptyHidden` collection.

If you want to delete them, I suggest to first select the top-level object of your asset, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > Children, Alt P > *Clear Parents (keep transforms)*, then you can select the empty objects as previous .2 and delete them without disrupting your asset.

Comment: Thank you friend, This helps a lot. Yes they are empties. Apparently, they come in with the Fusion hierarchy. I was able to move them into the EmptyHidden Collection as you suggested. Great trick!  

All of the body naming is removed during this process, so I'm left with a bunch of Body1.xxx labels. I'll need to decide which is more of a PITA. 

There is one remaining issue of why these come in with the import for some assemblies and not others. From what I can tell, the hierarchies are structured the same, and my import settings are the same.  I'll keep experimenting.

Best regards.